# Having Problems with lists

Tags: python, list, oop, for-loop, dictionary

I am trying to practise classes, objects, lists and for loops. I am trying to make a program which is a student gradebook. I will have a menu which continueally loops and when you press 1: It will let the user input a new student with his age,science results,maths results and english results. When the user has inputted the name,age,science result,maths result, english result, I want the user to input the schoolclass they want to add the student to (I have 4 preset schoolclasses):12A,12B,12C,12D and when the user inputs one of the classes, it appends the name of the student to the specific schoolclass. Now here is the catch: I want to be able to add new schoolclasses which I will also put in the menu. This is whhy i can't just put an if statement to compare if the inputted value is e.g. "12A" but I have to check every value in the schoolClasses class.

Here is the code:

```
#global variables
name = ""
allStudents = []


class Student:
    name = ""      
    age = 0
    science = 0
    maths = 0
    english = 0
    def __init__(self,name,age,science,maths,english):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.science = science
        self.maths = maths
        self.english = english
        print(self.name)
        print(self.age)
        print(self.science)
        print(self.maths)
        print(self.english)

    def average(self):
        self.Averagenum = (self.science + self.maths + self.english) / 3
        print("The average is",self.Averagenum)

ef mainFunct():
global allStudents

workClass = []
global classes
dictStudent = []
mainBool = True

while mainBool == True:

    print("WElcome to rafs student grade book a")
    #while True:
        #try:
    menu = int(input("1) Add a new student to a class 2) Delete Student 3) Highest to lowest grades 4) Change student to a new class 5) add new marks 6) Change"))
            #break
        #except ValueError:
                  #print("Please enter in a number")

    if menu == 1:


        name = input("What is their name")
        age = input("What is their age")
        while True:
            science = int(input("What was their science result out of 100"))
            if science <= 100:
                break
        while True:
            maths = int(input("What was their maths result out of 100"))
            if maths <= 100:
                break
        while True:
            english = int(input("What was their english result out of 100"))
            if english <= 100:
                break
        student = Student(name,age,science,maths,english)
        allStudents.append(student)
        while True:
            whatClass = input("What class would you like to add a new student (12A,12B,12C,12D): ")
            for i in range(len(classes)):
                #if whatClass == classes[i]:
                if classes.count(whatClass) == 0:
                    print("Need to make a new list then")
                    classes.append(whatClass)
                    print(classes)
                    break
mainFunct()
```

So what I really don't know how to do is I basically I want a list with the number of schoolclasses there are and then I can call the schoolclass to see all the different students there are in the school class.

Visually this might look something like: 
classes = 12A ("Josh","Marvin") 12B ("Margaret","Tristan")

I will also have something in the mainFunct()

like if menu == 3:
     addNewSchoolClass = input("Please enter in a new schoolclass that you want to add")..

Sorry if I have explained this pretty badly as I am still very bad at python. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been working on fixing this for ages.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That code will not compile. Can you provide at least working code?

Comment: As for your question, before trying to add an "add schoolclass" feature, you should remove the classes from the text and put it in a list beforehand  (ex: classes =  ["2A","12B","12C", "12D"]). Then you can write the code so it works with any number of items in the list. When that works, you can start asking yourself how the user could add entries to that list - it will probably become more obvious to you at that point.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/dG91XKUZ Here is the full application. By the way I have changed a little bit up in the mainfunction as in the classes list, I have managed to append the name after the user inputs either 12A, 12B, 12C, 12C. What I want the program to do is if I do something like print(classes["12A"]) Then it prints everyone is in the class. I think the only way to do this is by using a nested list in a dictionary or a triple nested list but I'm not very sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've improved your program using some sugar syntax from Python. I've tried to apply best practices:

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age, science, maths, english):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.science = science
        self.maths = maths
        self.english = english

   @property
        def average(self):
        return (self.science + self.maths + self.english) / 3.0

   def __str__(self):
        return "Student %s, Average: %s" % (self.name, str(self.average))

def main():
     in_program = True
     students = []
     classes = {"12A": [], "12B": [], "12C": []}
     print("Welcome to rafs student grade book a")
     while in_program:
        try:
            menu = int(raw_input(
            "1) Add a new student to a class \n2) Delete Student \n3) Highest to lowest grades \n4) Change student to a new class \n5) add new marks \n6) Change\n"))
        except ValueError:
            print "Insert a number please"
            continue
        if menu == 1:
            name = raw_input("What is their name: ")
            age = raw_input("What is their age: ")
            science_score = read_score("science", 100)
            math_score = read_score("math", 100)
            english_score = read_score("english", 100)
            student = Student(name, age, science_score, math_score, english_score)
            students.append(student)

            existent_class, class_ = read_class(classes)
            if existent_class:
                class_.append(student)
            else:
                classes.update({class_: [student, ]})

        if menu == 3:
            list_sorted = sorted(students, key=lambda student_: student_.average)
            print [str(item) for item in list_sorted]

def read_class(available_classes):
    class_ = raw_input(
        "What class would you like to add a new student %s: " % ' '.join([k for k, v in available_classes.iteritems()]))

    if class_ in available_classes:
        return True, available_classes[class_]

    return False, class_

def read_score(subject, limit):
    score = limit + 1
    while score > limit:
        try:
            score = int(raw_input("What was their %s result out of 100: " % subject))
        except ValueError:
            print "Insert a number please"
            continue
    return score

main()
```

Please add any additional information to improve your question

Obviously this is not a complete answer and its intention is to show how to work with Python, from this you can imagine any improvement to the program.

Comment: Thanks!, This is super helpful (but slightly confusing). Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you find any problem with the code I can help you.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I don't really understand what is happening for:

existent_class, class_ = read_class(classes)
            if existent_class:
                class_.append(student)
            else:
                classes.update({class_: [student, ]})

        if menu == 3:
            list_sorted = sorted(students, key=lambda student_: student_.average)
            print [str(item) for item in list_sorted]

I don't really understand what it happening here as you have just put if existent_class: without putting setting it to == to something.

Comment: @mre12345 in almost any programming language when you have a Boolean sentence without explicit comparing, you're comparing to True implicitly.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help imarban!! I have finally completed the program and I am very proud of it. I couldn't of done it without you.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the answer as correct to help other users.